# Selenium webdriver chrome exception

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid, remotewebdriver

I am working with Selenium Java for Automation and I am using

```
String Node = "http://" + nodeIP + ":5557/wd/hub";
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(Node), cap);
```

to get a new client browser instance but I get an exception as mentioned below

```
org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException chrome
org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException: 

The requested URL could not be retrieved
SAP Cloud Services Infrastructure Management
```

Is there by any means do we have any flags which can't correct these ?
I mean from Java program can we set and avoid this exception ?
If so how do we set them for Chrome or IE ?

Answer (score 0):

UnsupportedCommandException is mostly due to host file issues. 
You may have to look at https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=3280 .

Most generic solution can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16214915/unable-to-call-firefoxdriver-constructor).

Comment: is there a way we can set these from Java Code.

I am wondering if there is any way from which we can set these right 
I mean for a chrome browser or IE.

Comment: You can as profile.setPreference(FirefoxProfile.ALLOWED_HOSTS_PREFERENCE, "alias1,alias2"); Please see https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=3280#c20

Comment: above link is broken and redirects to a page which doesn't exist. I am not aware of what exactly to use in the parameters alias1, alias 2. If you can let me know a bit in detail pls