# I am using the below code for launching the firefox browser but am getting an error

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver

I am using the below code for launching the firefox browser but am getting the error as follow. please help me in resolving the issue.

**Code:**

```
public class FirstClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(); 

        try {
            driver.wait(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
        driver.get("www.Google.com");
        driver.close();
    }
}
```

**Error:**

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException: Bad request

Command duration or timeout: 5.81 seconds

Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b', time: '2016-03-15 16:57:40'

System info: host: 'ATUMKURX-MOBL', ip: '10.223.181.206', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_74'

Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
```

**content of host file:**

```
localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.

127.0.0.1       localhost

::1             localhost

127.0.0.1       LIUYUNKX-MOBL.gar.corp.intel.com # LMS GENERATED LINE
```

Comment: which version of webdriver and firefox are you using?

Comment: Webdriver 2.53.0
Firefox 44.0

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver()
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
driver.close();
```

Comment: Used the above suggested code but still issue remains the same.

Comment: This exception is thrown when you have more than 1 entry of 127.0.0.1. See the issue here - https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/3280

Comment: i have refered this but i have only one entry on 127.0.0.1 in the host file, the same i have shared in my question

Comment: @Amith - 
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 LIUYUNKX-MOBL.gar.corp.intel.com # LMS GENERATED LINE

Above are the two entries.

Comment: Thanks a lot, issue got resolved. left the last line of the host file was not commented.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of  `driver.wait(5000);` use `Thread.sleep(5000);`

Below code is working for me :-

```
  try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
    driver.get("www.Google.com");
    driver.close();
    System.out.println("Edd");

}
```

While using Thread is not recommended you can use implicitlyWait also:-

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

implicitlyWait wait through out your script for every element selenium looking for

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: Used the above suggested code but still issue remains the same

Comment: provide the full stacktrace and your code if possible with firefox (not the driver)   version if possible.

Comment: have you tried this :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16214915/unable-to-call-firefoxdriver-constructor

Comment: @optimist_creeper: i have shared the stacktrace in my question and the content of my host file. fire fox version is 44.0

Comment: @ShubhamJain: i refer that but i have an doubt that in my host file there is only "127.0.0.1 localhost" there is nothing other than that.

Comment: Have u tried without try catch block .. is google opening then?

Comment: Thanks a lot, issue got resolved. left the last line of the host file was not commented.

Answer (score 0):

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver()
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
driver.quit();

if same issue exits, please upgrade selenium jar (http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/) to latest, and updat`enter code here`e firefox to latest and try..
```

Comment: Selenium version is new 2.53.0 and hopefully there is something to do with host file. have a look at the content of the host file which i have shared and suggest me if there is anything to update?

Comment: Please check in host file, and all content should be commented. and save and run again

# 127.0.0.1 localhost

#::1 localhost

#127.0.0.1 LIUYUNKX-MOBL.gar.corp.intel.com # LMS GENERATED LINE

Comment: Thanks a lot, issue got resolved. left the last line of the host file was not commented.

And after the run got success full am getting the below in the console, could you please help me in knowing what is this?

"Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"

Comment: What project are you running? Are there problems/symptoms beyond what
you're seeing in the console? What version of Eclipse are you using? Basically those message will not be affecting ur selenium test... 
do you have any other os in your machine

Comment: Am just setting up my for new project which was supposed to start in few months. there are no other problems in the console which i shared. Am using "Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2)" esclipse

Answer (score 0):

Below is the Answer:

Last line of the host file was not commented.

After commenting the last line the issue got resolved.